# Nib simulated metrics size must match simulator size?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nib

I am currently developing an app targeting the iOS 7 environment.
I found that if I set the nib simulator metrics size to 4in with simulator size 3.5in, when the app launches, it will give me a screen with cut off elements.
And if I set the simulator size to 4in with a simulator metrics of 3.5in, the layout will be shrunk.
So basically it's like a 4in screen on a 3.5in device and vice versa.

But when I navigate away from that screen (within the app) and come back to the page, it will resize to the size it should be.
But it seems to be a hit or miss. It happens to some of the views, but some other views like  `UITableView` do not resize properly.
Another thing to note is that even when I set the metric size to None or Freeform, it will not auto-resize to the proper size.

Is this normal?
My fear is that if I deploy via TestFlight, and I had the nib set to one of the size and my testers have device of the other size, they will see improperly sized screens.

Does anyone have similar experience? Any fix to this problem?

Comment: Do you use auto layout or are you still using old style springs and struts?

Comment: oops should've mentioned that. Yes I am using autolayout.